# Cookies not being sent in request headers in production but was working fine in localhost

Tags: node.js, cookies, axios, next.js, vercel

I have a node.js backend deployed on heroku and next.js frontend deployed on vercel. I am setting a HttpCookie from the backend like this:

```
.cookie("secureCookie", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: "none",
      secure: true,
    })
```

and sending from frontend using axios for API route protection like this:

```
import { Event, Razorpay } from "@typings/event";
import axios from "axios";
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
export const createEvent = async (
  title: string,
  description: string,
  date: Date,
  time: Date,
  price: number,
  owner: string,
  poster: string,
  banner?: string,
  event_id?: string
): Promise<{ success: string; event: Event }> => {
  const res = await axios(`${process.env.BASE_URL}api/event/create`, {
    withCredentials: true,
    method: event_id ? "PATCH" : "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
    },
    data: {
      title,
      description,
      date,
      time,
      price,
      owner,
      poster,
      banner,
      event_id,
    },
  });
  return res.data;
};
```

While this is working on localhost, I am facing trouble in the production mode. The cookie is being set on the vercel.app but it is not being sent back to heroku server using withCredentials:"true". Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider some rules in both backend and front:

```
// server.js backend
const corsOptions = {
 origin : function(origin , callback){
   return callback(null, true);
 },
 optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
 credentials: true,
 }
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Now you can send request from frontend like this:

```
const req = await fetch(URL , {
 method : "POST",
 credentials : "include", // to send httpOnly cockie
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
  },
  body : JSON.stringify({
    email : "abc@gmail.com",
    password  : "Asdf12"
 })
 })
const result = await req.json()
```

and also in coockie sameSite : "None"

```
.cookie("secureCookie", token, {
  httpOnly: true,
  sameSite: "None",
  secure: true,
})
```

Comment: Doesn't work even after doing all this

Comment: Do you use `cookie-parser` module for cookiess in Node.js?

Comment: OMG, you should send the request from browser not from the next.js default API. because when you send from next.js API it acts like the server you can not send cookie instead you should call the request like inside `useEffect` where the cookie is available for first time

Comment: What do you mean by request from the browser and not from next.js default API? I am calling the createEvent API from a button click so the cookies are present there. Moreover this is working locally so the actual problem I think is because of cors because the cookie is being set in the application tab but not being displayed in the request headers

Comment: Did you find a solution ?